# Windows 7 ignores my JAVA_HOME created by my account

Tags: java, windows, java-8, java-home, system32

How do I persuade Windows to use the JDK of my account instead of default java placed in the system (admin) "Windows\System32" which run java 1.6.

When i tape :
`where java` i got the two paths (my java and system one).
when i run echo `%JAVA_HOME%` i got my java (1.8) but when i execute `java -version` i got the system one (1.6)

How could i erase the system one without having the habilitation to admin.

PS : i cannot acces to admin variables system.

Comment: Java doesn't care about JAVA_HOME. It just goes from the PATH.

Comment: yrh i know, i set the java_bin into PATH but still not working !

Comment: So you didn't do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Set the path of your Java bin folder into the path variable e.g. if your Java is installed at `C:\java\jdk1.8.0_09`, set `C:\java\jdk1.8.0_09\bin` as the **first entry** in the `PATH` environment variable.

Alternatively, you can set `C:\java\jdk1.8.0_09` into `JAVA_HOME` and then `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` into the `PATH` environment variable. Make sure to make this the **first entry** in the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: i've set this java_bin in PATH but in my Account PATH, then this PATH account will be added to the PATH system. not wworking

Comment: @Mirlo - I am 100% sure that you are doing mistake in setting this. I can help you solve it immediately if you can show the screenshot of your java installation folder and the screenshot of `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: @Mirlo see https://superuser.com/a/878382 and https://superuser.com/q/367194